# How do I remove a DIV I created using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, dynamic

When user clicks an object, I want to generate menu for it.

```
$(".thumbImage").click(function(e){

    var xCoord = e.pageX;
    var yCoord = e.pageY;

    var content = "<div class='thumbMenu' id='tempMenu'>THE MENU IS HERE</div>";
    $(this).after(content);

    $("#tempMenu").css("visibility","visible");
    $("#tempMenu").css("left",xCoord-30);
    $("#tempMenu").css("top",yCoord-30);
    return false;

});
```

Now I want that when user takes the mouse away, the div with id = "tempMenu" should get removed. It shouldn't give trouble if user clicks some other thumbImage.

Here's my present code :

```
$(".thumbImage").mouseout(function(e){
    $("#tempMenu").remove();
    return false;
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work well.

Comment: Is there anything reported in your console.log?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you creating multiple elements with the same id.
If you have multiple elements with class thumbImage by clicking on them you create element with id tempMenu after them.

Maybe you should remove id from created element and call removing like this:

```
$(".thumbImage").mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).next(".thumbMenu").remove();
    return false;
});
```

Also you can create your div like this:

```
var myDiv = $("<div/>", {
  "class" : "thumbMenu",
  text : "THE MENU IS HERE",
  "visibility": "visible",
  "left": xCoord-30,
  "top" : yCoord-30
})

$(this).after(myDiv);
```

[Link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full HTML markup so I used `body` as the selected element.  You may want to change this for your own use.  I used the `.on()` event handler (http://api.jquery.com/on/)  and the `mouseleave` event to remove your `#tempMenu`.

**jQuery**

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', '#tempMenu', function() {
     $(this).remove();
     return false;
});
```